# Using a D3D11 texture in a D3D12 application

Tags: directx-11, directx-12

My application is written in D3D12. We have a VR plugin that provide a D3D11 shared texture. Can a D3D11 texture be "converted" into a D3D12 texture?

The only solution I found so far is to write D3D11onD3D12 code that would make use of that texture + the resources of the D3D12 app.

Answer (score 0):

Seems the only way is to write DX11 code that would make use of that texture. Then run this code on the D3D11On12 context.